# Configure automatic excluded directories and other directory types when they are present

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

In the Community Edition when I import a module IntelliJ goes through and tries to figure out which directories are what types. The modules I deal with sometimes have a `src` and a `test` directory, which work fine, but more often than not the test directory is actually named `tst`. IntelliJ likes to mark is as a "Sources" directory rather than "Tests". With the tools I am working with, the dependency configuration and generation of the `.iml` file happens after this, as well as using a modified build system that is not IntelliJ supported. I have to build via commandline which generates a `build` folder which I would like to have automatically excluded.

So a couple questions.

1. Can I configure IntelliJ to automatically recognize different folder names "Tests" and mark them as such?
2. Can I configure IntelliJ to automatically mark a folder as excluded when it is present in a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can't configure it, the list is hard-coded. However, I've added "tst" to the list of names that are recognized as test source roots; that fix will be included in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.
2. You can add "build" to Settings | File Types | Files and folders to ignore. Then IntelliJ will ignore the directories and files named "build" anywhere in your project structure. Given that "build" is a fairly common name, this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: 15.0.1 still doesn't detect "tst" folders as test.